# SQL Server BULK INSERT FROM different schemas

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I have a database that can have data updated from two external parties.
Each of those parties sends a pipe delimited text file that is BULK INSERTED into the staging table.
I now want to change the scheme for one of the parties by adding a few columns, but this is unfortunately breaking the BULK INSERT for the other party even though the new columns are all added as NULLABLE.

Is there any obvious solution to this?

TABLE SCHEMA:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CUSTOMER_ENTRY_LOAD](
[CARD_NUMBER] [varchar](12) NULL,
[TITLE] [varchar](6) NULL,
[LAST_NAME] [varchar](34) NULL,
[FIRST_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
[MIDDLE_NAME] [varchar](40) NULL,
[NAME_ON_CARD] [varchar](26) NULL,
[H_ADDRESS_PREFIX] [varchar](50) NULL,
[H_FLAT_NUMBER] [varchar](5) NULL,
[H_STREET_NUMBER] [varchar](10) NULL,
[H_STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX] [varchar](5) NULL,
[H_STREET] [varchar](50) NULL,
[H_SUBURB] [varchar](50) NULL,
[H_CITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
[H_POSTCODE] [varchar](4) NULL,
[P_ADDRESS_PREFIX] [varchar](50) NULL,
[P_FLAT_NUMBER] [varchar](5) NULL,
[P_STREET_NUMBER] [varchar](10) NULL,
[P_STREET_NUMBER_SUFFIX] [varchar](5) NULL,
[P_STREET] [varchar](50) NULL,
[P_SUBURB] [varchar](50) NULL,
[P_CITY] [varchar](50) NULL,
[P_POSTCODE] [varchar](4) NULL,
[H_STD] [varchar](3) NULL,
[H_PHONE] [varchar](7) NULL,
[C_STD] [varchar](3) NULL,
[C_PHONE] [varchar](10) NULL,
[W_STD] [varchar](3) NULL,
[W_PHONE] [varchar](7) NULL,
[W_EXTN] [varchar](5) NULL,
[DOB] [smalldatetime] NULL,
[EMAIL] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DNS_STATUS] [bit] NULL,
[DNS_EMAIL] [bit] NULL,
[CREDITCARD] [char](1) NULL,
[PRIMVISACUSTID] [int] NULL,
[PREFERREDNAME] [varchar](100) NULL,
[STAFF_NUMBER] [varchar](50) NULL,
[CUSTOMER_ID] [int] NULL,
[IS_ADDRESS_VALIDATED] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

BULK INSERT STATEMENT:

```
SET @string_temp = 'BULK INSERT customer_entry_load FROM '+char(39)+@inpath
+@current_file+'.txt'+char(39)+' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '+char(39)+'|'+char(39)
+', MAXERRORS=1000,  ROWTERMINATOR = '+char(39)+'\n'+char(39)+')'
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
EXEC(@string_temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179250.aspx) describes how to use a format file to handle the scenario where the target table has more columns than the source file. An alternative that can sometimes be easier is to create a view on the table and `BULK INSERT` into the view instead of the table; this possibility is described in the same documentation.

And please always mention your SQL Server version.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I wasn't sure that using a format file helped, because in some circumstances the target has more columns than the source and in some it doesn't. I was wondering if there was a way to accomplish this with 1 BULK INSERT statement? SQL Server version is 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

Using [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) with BULK allows you to use your file in a query. You can use that to format the data and select only the columns you need.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that option. It would still require 2 BULK INSERT statements for each file though, but I might be able to find a way to use it

Answer (score 0):

In the end I have handled the two different cases with two different BULK INSERT statements (depending on which file is being processed). It seems like there isn't a way to do what I was trying to do with one statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the format file idea supplied by @Pondlife.

Adapt your insert dynamically based on the input file name (provided there are unique differneces between the external parties).  Using a CASE statement, simply select the correct format file based on the unique identifier in the file name.

```
DECLARE @formatFile varchar (max);

Set @formatFile =
CASE 
    WHEN @current_file LIKE '%uniqueIdentifier%'
    THEN 'file1' 
    ELSE 'file2'
END

SET @string_temp = 'BULK INSERT customer_entry_load FROM '+char(39)+@inpath
+@current_file+'.txt'+char(39)+' WITH (FORMATFILE = '+char(39)+@formatFile+char(39)
')'
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
EXEC(@string_temp)
```

Hope that helps!